# android espresso webview access element in iframe

Tags: android, iframe, android-espresso

This time I try to use espresso to test my app.
I use webview to open the url and check below html code 
I face the question that I can`t access the element in iframe.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="mainFrame" src="Address/Default.aspx" scrolling="no" 
    style="border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 432px; position: absolute;">
      <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <button onclick = "one function">
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I copy the XPTH that is **/html/body/button** and code

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "/html/body/button")).perform(webClick());
```

However, I get **Atom evaluation returned null!** and I can not get element.
Can espresso get element inside iframe? I can get element not in iframe.

Answer (score 3):

> As the button is inside an `iframe`, thus we need to use `.inWindow(selectFrameByIdOrName("mainFrame"))`

```
onWebView()
    .inWindow(selectFrameByIdOrName("mainFrame"))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "/html/body/button")).perform(webClick());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the iframe is on a different domain the `inWindow(selectFrameByIdOrName("..."))` will throw an exception; "Blocked a frame with origin "https://iframe-url/" from accessing a cross-origin frame.". How can you bypass this?

Comment: Actually I've just found out how it can be done - refer to: https://medium.com/azimolabs/android-webview-automation-testing-6311df8fe42e (key is to use UiAutomator)